# how to find out the size of file and directory in java without creating the object?

Tags: java, filesize

First please dont overlook because you might think it as common question, this is not. I know how to find out size of file and directory using `file.length` and [Apache `FileUtils.sizeOfDirectory`](http://commons.apache.org/io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#sizeOfDirectory%28java.io.File%29).

My problem is, in my case files and directory size is too big (in hundreds of mb). When I try to find out size using above code (e.g. creating file object) then my program becomes so much resource hungry and slows down the performance.

Is there any way to know the size of file without creating object?

I am using 
for files File file1 = new file(fileName); long size = file1.length();

and for directory, File dir1 = new file (dirPath); long size = fileUtils.sizeOfDirectiry(dir1);

I have one parameter which enables size computing. If parameter is false then it goes smoothly. If false then program lags or hangs.. I am calculating size of 4 directory and 2 database files.

Comment: A `File` object doesn't read the file into memory, AFAIK.  So there shouldn't be a resource issue.

Comment: what is `fileUtils.sizeOfDirectory`? is it an internal utility or a 3rd party?

Comment: @Ronk it's from apache commons http://commons.apache.org/io/api-1.1/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#sizeOfDirectory(java.io.File)

Comment: I am not sure if it loads in to memory, but it gives me big performance hit :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question..

This is not the best solution but works in my case..

I have created a batch script to get the size of the directory and then read it in java program. It gives me less execution time when number of files in directory are more then 1L (That is always in my case).. sizeOfDirectory takes around 30255 ms and with batch script i get 1700 ms.. For less number of files batch script is costly.

Answer (score 4):

File objects are very lightweight. Either there is something wrong with your code, or the problem is not with the file objects but with the HD access necessary for getting the file size. If you do that for a large *number* of files (say, tens of thousands), then the harddisk will do a lot of seeks, which is pretty much the slowest operation possible on a modern PC (by several orders of magnitude).

Comment: I think yes, It might be because of disk operations. I studied the code and I didnt find close for any file opened. might be the issue. Let me check..

Comment: @swd: you don't need to open files to get their size. What *is* your code doing?

Comment: File file1 = new File(fileName); long size = file1.length();

Comment: @swd: OK, that's the correct way to do it, but the file is not opened.

Comment: and for directory, File dir1 = new file (dirPath); long size = fileUtils.sizeOfDirectiry(dir1);  I have one parameter which enables size computing. If parameter is false then it goes smoothly. If false then program lags or hangs.. I am calculating size of 4 directory and 2 database files.

Answer (score 3):

A File is just a wrapper for the file path. It doesn't matter how big the file is only its file name.

When you want to get the size of all the files in a directory, the OS needs to read the directory and then lookup each file to get its size.  Each access takes about 10 ms (because that's a typical seek time for a hard drive) So if you have 100,000 file it will take you about 17 minutes to get all their sizes.

The only way to speed this up is to get a faster drive. e.g. Solid State Drives have an average seek time of 0.1 ms but it would still take 10 second or more to get the size of 100K files.

BTW: The size of each file doesn't matter because it doesn't actually read the file. Only the file entry which has it s size.

---

EDIT: For example, if I try to get the sizes of a large directory. It is slow at first but much faster once the data is cached.

```
$ time du -s /usr
2911000 /usr

real    0m33.532s
user    0m0.880s
sys 0m5.190s

$ time du -s /usr
2911000 /usr

real    0m1.181s
user    0m0.300s
sys 0m0.840s

$ find /usr | wc -l
259934
```

The reason the look up is so fast the fist time is that the files were all installed at once and most of the information is available continuously on disk. Once the information is in memory, it takes next to no time to read the file information.

Timing FileUtils.sizeOfDirectory("/usr") take under 8.7 seconds.  This is relatively slow compared with the time it takes du, but it is processing around 30K files per second.

An alterative might be to run `Runtime.exec("du -s "+directory);` however, this will only make a few seconds difference at most.  Most of the time is likely to be spent waiting for the disk if its not in cache.

Comment: @Peter Lawrey: These numbers don't make sense. I have a standard Dell laptop and I| just asked windows to get me the size of the `Windows` directory - it got me 10.7GB, 57K files + 11K directories and this took less than 30 sec.

Comment: @RonK, Caching makes a big difference. It appears to me it was about to get all that information in under 3K access to the disk (a typical laptop drive take 12 ms to do a seek) because the OS often reads in more than it needs to in the hope you will need that information later. e.g. It often reads in say 32KB, even though a typical file entry might be 512 bytes long.  This means for every read you have actually loaded 64 entries which may be useful later. If you do exactly the same thing again, it should be much faster.

Comment: If you down vote but don't comment, its like says I know what you are doing wrong but I'm keeping to myself. We are all hear to learn, and I appreciate constructive criticism.

Comment: @Peter Lawrey: Caching was indeed helpful, it took 3sec now. Still, the numbers indicate a much faster access than indicated in the above question - again on my laptop, 57GB of files (200K of files) - less than 1min to count and sum, so either the apache common IO pack has a performance problem when compared to the OS, or something else is causing the performance difference

Comment: You have already determined that how the files are accessed and whether they are in memory can make a 10x difference to performance. A Windows directory is typically installed mostly all at once and in a small series of updates.  This means it can be fairly optimally arranged. Also because it is part of the OS, a good portion will be in cache already. If you are going to do a comparison you need to run Apache FileUtils.sizeOfDirectory on the same directory.

Comment: Already did - Windows counted the entire HD in less than 1min, Apache took 7min...
It can also be a problem with the native code standing behind the `FileSystem` implementation ... but I have no idea as to how to investigate that

Comment: This does appear to be very system dependant. Apache took 9 second to scan my entire HD (after it was in cache) with about 300K files. By comparison `du -s` to 1.2 seconds. ;)

Answer (score 2):

We had a similar performance problem with File.listFiles() on directories with large number of files.

Our setup was one folder with 10 subfolders each with 10,000 files.
The folder was on a network share and not on the machine running the test.

We were using a FileFilter to only accept files with known extensions or a directory so we could recourse down the directories.

Profiling revealed that about 70% of the time was spent calling File.isDirectory (which I assume Apache is calling).  There were two calls to isDirectory for each file (one in the filter and one in the file processing stage).

File.isDirectory was slow cause it had to hit the network share for each file.

Reversing the order of the check in the filter to check for valid name before valid directory saved a lot of time, but we still needed to call isDirectory for the recursive lookup.

My solution was to implement a version of listFiles in native code, that would return a data structure that contained all the metadata about a file instead of just the filename like File does.

This got rid of the performance problem but added a maintenance problem of having to native code maintained by Java developers (lucking we only supported one OS).

Comment: Right, I have same issue.. my folder is also on network.. Stackr suggested to use Files class which gives you metadata information of file.. but we will have to wait til that time.. Also I fear there is no directory support which will again lead us to call listFiles !!

Answer (score 1):

I think that you need to read the Meta-Data of a file.
Read this tutorial for more information. This might be the solution you are looking for:
http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/fileAttr.html

Comment: I cant have "Files" class!! in which package it is declared

Comment: Thats in JAva 7.. i m using java6.. :(

Answer (score 0):

I'll add to what Peter Lawrey answered and add that when a directory has a lot of files inside it (directly, not in sub dirs) - the time it takes for `file.listFiles()` it extremely slow (I don't have exact numbers, I know it from experience). The amount of files has to be large, several thousands if I remember correctly - if this is your case, what `fileUtils` will do is actually try to load all of their names at once into memory - which can be consuming.

If that is your situation - I would suggest restructuring the directory to have some sort of hierarchy that will ensure a small number of files in each sub-directory.